# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una ProgressBar pero con bloques de diferentes colores?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, progressbar

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que toma archivos con información de pruebas a ensambles y tiene que haber una `ProgressBar` que aumente cada que se haga una prueba, si la prueba falla el bloque que aumenta debe ser rojo y si pasa debe ser verde.

Intenté con la `ProgressBar` de visualStudio pero no encontré cómo cambiarle los colores a cada bloque, así que estuve intentando simular una con un `TableLayoutPanel`, el total de columnas es la meta que se debe alcanzar de pruebas y cada que hacen una prueba la idea era meter un panel y cambiarle el fondo de color, pero no pasa nada.

Aquí les dejo el código:

```
tlpBar.ColumnCount = Settings.Default.target;
tlpBar.Controls.AddRange(new Panel[Settings.Default.target]);
foreach(Control ctrl in tlpBar.Controls)
{
    ctrl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

`tlpBar` es el `TableLayoutPanel` y `Settings.Default.target` es la meta de pruebas que se tienen que hacer.

Seguramente el problema yace en el `new Panel[Settings.Default.target]`, porque intenté hacerlo con `tlpBar.Controls.Add(new Panel());` y sí funcionó, pero no con el `AddRange` y todos los paneles.

Y tampoco puedo hacer que las columnas del `TableLayoutPanel` se distribuyan en toda la barra con el mismo tamaño.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una mejor forma hace mucho tiempo, pero olvidé ponerla.
Lo hice con un `PictureBox` y dibujaba rectangulos dependiendo del tiempo que duraba la prueba.

```
private void timeLines_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox timeLine = (PictureBox)sender;

    for (int i = 0; i < testDataArray.Length; i++)
    {
        TimeSpan startTimeDistance = testDataArray[i].startDateTime - shiftStart;
        TimeSpan endTimeDistance = testDataArray[i].endDateTime - shiftStart;
        float startBlock = (float)(startTimeDistance.TotalHours * timeLine.Width / HPT);
        float endBlock = (float)((endTimeDistance.TotalHours * timeLine.Width / HPT));
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(testDataArray[i].brush, startBlock, 0, endBlock - startBlock, timeLine.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), startBlock, 0, startBlock, timeLine.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), endBlock, 0, endBlock, timeLine.Height);

    }
}
```

- `testDataArra` es un arreglo donde tengo la hora en que empezó y terminó la prueba y el color con el que se tiene que pintar.
- `shiftStart` es la hora en que comienza de mi línea de tiempo.
- `HPT` son las horas que representa mi línea del tiempo en total.

Explicación paso a paso:

En esta parte calculo el tiempo que ha pasado desde que empezó mi línea del tiempo hasta la hora en que comenzó la prueba. Esto para saber en que bloque de tiempo de mi línea de tiempo está la prueba.

```
TimeSpan startTimeDistance = testDataArray[i].startDateTime - shiftStart;
TimeSpan endTimeDistance = testDataArray[i].endDateTime - shiftStart;
```

En esta parte hago la conversión de tiempo a pixeles para poder dibujarlo en el `PictureBox`. Es una simple regla de 3.

```
float startBlock = (float)(startTimeDistance.TotalHours * timeLine.Width / HPT);
float endBlock = (float)((endTimeDistance.TotalHours * timeLine.Width / HPT));
```

En esta parte ya hago el dibujo del rectángulo y su contorno:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(testDataArray[i].brush, startBlock, 0, endBlock - startBlock, timeLine.Height);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), startBlock, 0, startBlock, timeLine.Height);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), endBlock, 0, endBlock, timeLine.Height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Que te parece con un `richtextbox`[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tenemos dos botones una que simula una prueba pasada y el otro que simula una prueba fallada, simplemente cambias el color y agregas un █ (U+2588) bloque entero.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RTxtBx.SelectionStart = RTxtBx.TextLength;
            RTxtBx.SelectionLength = 0;
            RTxtBx.SelectionColor = Color.Red;//de fallo
            RTxtBx.AppendText("█");
            RTxtBx.SelectionColor = RTxtBx.ForeColor;
        }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RTxtBx.SelectionStart = RTxtBx.TextLength;
            RTxtBx.SelectionLength = 0;
            RTxtBx.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;//de exito
            RTxtBx.AppendText("█");
            RTxtBx.SelectionColor = RTxtBx.ForeColor;
        }
```

Comment: ¿Pero cómo haría para que el tamaño de la barra fuera proporcional al número de pruebas que llevan con respecto al total de pruebas que se tienen que hacer?
Por ejemplo: si llevan 2 pruebas y se tienen que hacer 10, la barra debería estar rellenada a la quinta parte. ¿Cómo controlo el tamaño de esos bloques?

Comment: usa una regla de 3 el total de cuadros entre total de pruebas por pruebas efectuadas igual a cuadros agregados

Comment: Pero el bloque de texto que propones es de un tamaño fijo, ¿cómo sincronizar para que el número de bloques que caben en el RichTextBox sea el mismo que el total de pruebas que se tienen que hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, ya pude encontrar la forma:

```
for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            Panel pnl = new Panel();
            pnl.Size = new Size(pnlProgressBar.Size.Width / total, pnlProgressBar.Size.Height);
            pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
            pnl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            if(i % 2 == 0)
            {
                pnl.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                pnl.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            pnlProgressBar.Controls.Add(pnl);
        }
```

Simplemente puse un Panel y dentro de él empecé a meter más paneles. Todavía tiene un problema y es que al final queda un pequeño espacio en blanco. Me imagino que es porque el resultado de la división es flotante y la función acepta enteros, así que lo redondea y esos decimales perdidos dejan ese espacio en blanco. 
Si alguien tiene una idea de cómo arreglar eso u otra forma de hacer una `ProgressBar` es bienvenido de comentar.